# Recieving "Error in .intersectExtent(x, y, validate = TRUE) : Objects do not intersect" Message When Trying to Resample Rasters

Tags: r, gis, raster

I am running R amd have three `RasterLayer`s that I would like to resample three raster layers to the resolution of a courser scale raster (there are four rasters in total) for use in MaxEnt, but am receiving the following error:

`Error in .intersectExtent(x, y, validate = TRUE) : Objects do not intersect`

Two of the rasters already intersect with one another and line up perfectly but the other two do not intersect with any of the other raster layers.

I think this is an issue with the datum but I am having trouble changing the datum of the two "off" rasters so that they all match. On ArcGIS Pro, all four rasters are projected on top of each other and line up well, but their datums and underlying GCS's are different (with the exception of the two I previously mentioned).

Can someone help me in coding the following layers in the *D NAD 1983 2011* GCS?

This is the output I have been receiving:

```
dem <- raster("dem.asc")
sas <- raster("sas.asc")
sasb <- resample(sas, dem)
#Error in .intersectExtent(x, y, validate = TRUE) : 
#  Objects do not intersect
```

```
sas
#class      : RasterLayer 
#dimensions : 3185, 2615, 8328775 (nrow, ncol, ncell) 
#resolution : 30, 30 (x, y)
# extent    : 712518, 790968, 130036.7, 225586.7 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax) 
#crs        : +proj=aea +lat_0=24 +lon_0=-84 +lat_1=24 +lat_2=31.5 +x_0=400000 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs 
#source     : sas.asc 
#names      : sas 
#values     : -2147483648, 2147483647 (min, max)


dem
class      : RasterLayer
dimensions : 7125, 8208, 58482000 (nrow, ncol, ncell) 
resolution : 30, 30 (x, y) 
extent     : 7e+05, 946240, 385000, 598750 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax) 
crs        : +proj=aea +lat_0=24 +lon_0=-84 +lat_1=24 +lat_2=31.5 +x_0=400000 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs 
source     : dem.asc 
names      : dem
```

Dr. Hijmans, I see in the graph where you plot the rasters, they do not intersect, but in ArcGIS Pro, they indeed do overlap. I guess this is what is making me confused about this. The metadata for the DEM and SAS rasters are as follows:

**GPI Geospatial Inc DEM Metadata:**
Bare-earth 5-foot DEM as 32-bit floating point raster format in ARCGIS GRID Raster format in compliance with USGS LIDAR Base Specifications such as: georeferencing information, delivered without overlap and with no edge artifacts or mismatched, “NODATA” value for void areas, bridges removed from the surface, etc.

**Surficial Aquifer System Depth to Water Table Map Metadata:**
From the Florida Geological Survey. The Surficial Aquifer System (SAS) depth to water table surface grid was created by subtracting the water table surface grid from the DEM.

They both come from different sources but encompass the same geographic area. The original format of these layers are .ovr but I think MaxEnt only accepts .asc files. I converted them both to .asc for use in an Ecological Nice Model. I suppose my question to you is, why do they not intersect if they have the same CRS and encompass the same geographic region? Is there a workaround around this?

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
sasb <- resample(sas, dem)
#Error in .intersectExtent(x, y, validate = TRUE) : 
#  Objects do not intersect
```

says that `sas` and `dem` do not intersect. In that case you cannot resample one to another. Sometimes this is because the have a different coordinate reference system (crs), but from `show(sas)` and `dem` it is clear that they have the same coordinate reference system, but that they indeed do not overlap as you can see here:

```
library(raster)
es <- extent(712518, 790968, 130036.7, 225586.7)
ed <- extent(7e+05, 946240, 385000, 598750)
u = union(es, ed)
plot(u, col="white")
lines(es, lwd=3, col="blue")
lines(ed, lwd=3, col="red")
```

[image]

Comment: You should edit your question and add this information; not as comments